# Copy File from Box.com to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, file-transfer

I have a ~50,000 I need to upload to an S3 bucket.  These files already exist in Box.com  Is  there a way to write from Box to AWS using the AWSCLI?  It just seems like a wasted step to download from Box, then upload to AWS.

```
aws s3 cp https://ky.box.com/shared/static/ijblogo31nhwrtr0woyiressfy0e86ss.laz  s3://kyfromabove/elevation/LAZ/Phase1/

The user-provided path https://ky.box.com/shared/static/ijblogo31nhwrtr0woyiressfy0e86ss.laz does not exist.
```

Comment: How do you intend to download the files from box.com? Are the files publicly accessible, or do you need a login to access them? Based on [Download a folder from box using Terminal Command Line – Box Support](https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360049203113-Download-a-folder-from-box-using-Terminal-Command-Line), it would appear that you need to provide a TOKEN to prove that you are entitled to access the objects. See also: [java - Copy files from box folder to AWS s3 bucket - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778575/copy-files-from-box-folder-to-aws-s3-bucket)

Answer (score 0):

A pipe can help you solve this task! However, please do take note that AWS CLI will still download the file on your computer's memory instead of the file system!

```bash
curl -i -X GET \
  "https://ky.box.com/shared/static/ijblogo31nhwrtr0woyiressfy0e86ss.laz" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
  | aws s3 cp - s3://ian-horn-bucket/file1.laz
```

Comment: That sounds like a better option.  Thank you.

Comment: I ran a sample with the above syntax, not a whole lot going one.  An empty file with the name '-' uploads.  When I try to add the file name, I get the `file path not found` error.   I still feel like a download to memory is best solution.

Comment: Yes.  I was able to download to memory and push to AWS.  I'll provide a solution syntax.